# django management command: using LabelCommand

Tags: django, django-admin, python-2.7, django-manage.py

i want to pass argument along with this management command. i run this code from command line as

```
python manage.py example1 amita
```

where example1 is name of my file and amita is argument. on running this i am getting error.i am pasting the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "manage.py", line 79, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 68, in load_command_class
    return module.Command()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Command'
```

the code for  example1.py is below

```
from django.core.management.base import LabelCommand
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


def hello(name):
  print name

def hello1(name):
  print name


class LabelCommand(BaseCommand):
    """
    A management command which takes one or more arbitrary arguments
    (labels) on the command line, and does something with each of
    them.

    Rather than implementing ``handle()``, subclasses must implement
    ``handle_label()``, which will be called once for each label.

    If the arguments should be names of installed applications, use
    ``AppCommand`` instead.

    """
    args = '<label label ...>'
    label = 'label'

    def handle(self, *labels, **options):
        if not labels:
            raise CommandError('Enter at least one %s.' % self.label)

    output = []
    for label in labels:
        label_output = self.handle_label(label, **options)
        if label_output:
            output.append(label_output)
    return '\n'.join(output)



    def handle_label(self, label, **options):
        """
        Perform the command's actions for ``label``, which will be the
        string as given on the command line.

        """
        hello(label)
        hello1(label)
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

Comment: handle should be a method in the LabelCommand Class

Answer (score 2):

Django already has a LabelCommand class that you should use:

```
from django.core.management.base import LabelCommand
```

Then you just have to override the [handle_label](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-management-commands/#django.core.management.LabelCommand) command.